# How do I record all memory accesses of a process/file?

Tags: linux, caching, testing, memory, benchmarking

For testing a cache system, I need the memory access (read and writes) list for a particular process. The cache code is written in verilog. My application is for media processing, however I'm open to other applications as well.. So far I have been adding address references in the C++ code for PNG decoding (available here http://lodev.org/lodepng/)...

This is quite a tedious process and I'm looking for alternatives. I've even tried hacking into benchmarks like simplescalar as well as reading crash dumps, but to no avail...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth your time to look into Intel's [Pin](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool), so long as you're running on x86.

Their manual has [an example](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/62732/Pin/html/index.html#MAddressTrace) how to use Pin to instrument a binary to generate a memory trace.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I wanted, however what i didn't expect was a C++ Hello World code to have 180000 memory accesses :)

Comment: Glad to help. For C++, I am not surprised. :p

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  https://lwn.net/Articles/257209/

One tool is `Cachegrind` (part of [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/info/tools.html)). It's slow, but can tell you exact stats about memory accesses because it simulates your entire program on a virtual processor.

Another tool is [Oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/). It's a kernel module that uses statistical sampling to get data. It's not as accurate, but much lighter weight.